# Linq - Query a query result agains a list of strings

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of strings

```
List<string> firstNames = new List<string>();
```

I have a query result

```
var contacts = (from p in datacontext.Contact)
```

How Can I Query the original result (contacts) against the list of strings?

```
select * from contacts where contacts.firstname like firstNames
```

something like

```
firstNames.Any(x=>x.contacts.Contains(x))
```

Answer (score 3):

You should probably push the first names into the database query, like this:

```
var contacts = dataContext.Contacts.Where(c => firstNames.Contains(c.FirstName));
```

Now you used "like" in your sample query, so maybe you want:

```
var contacts = dataContext.Contacts
                     .Where(c => firstNames.Any(f => c.FirstName.Contains(f)));
```

If you could provide some concrete examples it would help.

EDIT: If you're *really* pulling back all the contacts from the database already into (say) a `List<Contact> contacts`, then you could use:

```
var matchingContacts = from contact in contacts
                       join name in firstNames
                       on contact.FirstName equals name
                       select contact;
```

Comment: I've run into problems doing things like this because of the mixed context (database versus memory). Is it not necessary to bring both sequences into a common context?

Comment: @JoelEtherton: It depends what you do, but passing a `List<string>` into the database query is reasonably common. The main thing is to do it the right way round so you don't end up bringing the whole database down to the client.

Comment: Be careful with 'Contains'. It could be translated to "SELECT * FROM t WHERE x IN('a','b','c', ...)". But most SQL implementations limit the length of the list. It might be possible to have a few dozens or hunderts items, but certainly not thousands!

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: Indeed. If there are just a few contacts in the database but lots of names in the list, then obviously it's best to pull all the contacts instead. If there are lots of names in the list *and* lots of contacts in the database, life becomes harder...

Comment: I would like to query the original query so that I am only hitting the database once.

Comment: @user971210: The code you've posted isn't even valid C# - you haven't shown the query actually being *executed*, and you haven't shown half the query. Are you really pulling back *all* the contacts from the database already?

Comment: (I've added an edit for that case if it's really what you want...)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Your edit works and allows me to get matching values, i've tested this. However i need to do a sql LIKE '%%'. instead of a join (as with your second example).  Is this possible

Comment: @user971210: What doesn't work in my second example? It's still not clear whether you're really happy to fetch all the contacts back to the client first...

Answer (score 0):

First, visit this link, download the class and add it to your App_Code folder:  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Then be sure to add "using System.Linq.Dynamic;"

Then construct your query like this:

```
    DatabaseDataContext db = new DatabaseDataContext();
    List<string> firstNames = new List<string>();

    //--- loop through names and build a where query
    string WhereClause = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < firstNames.Count(); i++)
    {
        string s = firstNames[i].ToLower();

        if (i != Communities.Length - 1)
            WhereClause += "FirstName.ToLower().Contains(\"" + s + "\") OR "; //--- first name is the field name in the db
        else
            WhereClause += "FirstName.ToLower().Contains(\"" + s + "\")";
    }

    //--- execute query and pass the dynamic where clause
    IQueryable contacts = db.Contacts
                          .Where(WhereClause)
                          .OrderBy("FirstName");
```

Good Luck!